# Observable List Nhibernate

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, data-binding, fluent-nhibernate, observablecollection

I'm attempting to have wpf databind to a collection of data models and, display them using datatemplates. Currently this is working perfectly when using an IList, however the databinding doesn't seem to pick up adds/removes on the IList. I'm assuming this is related to nhibernate's collections not being observable. I tried to implement [Nomad's WPF Collections](http://happynomad121.blogspot.com/2007/12/collections-for-wpf-and-nhibernate.html) without much luck (nH says it's not implementing UserCollectionType)

I'm not particularly keen on figuring out how to fix nomad's collections so I'm wondering if there's a better way of achieving an observable collection for wpf-nhibernate binding, especially now with the release of nH 3.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what trouble you had with my library.  It's worked fine for me and many other developers for years.  The provided sample app demonstrates this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [unhaddins](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/).You can find implementations of Observables Nhibernate`s collections

Comment: nice!...there are other very useful covered topics, like sessions lifetime management

Answer (score 1):

More simple way is to use property setter for observable collection initialization:

```
private ObservableCollection<ItemType> _items = new ObservableCollection<DynamicActivity>();
    public IList<DynamicActivity> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = new ObservableCollection<ItemType>(value); }
    }
```

Just need to define appropriate mapping strategy - use only access = "property".

Comment: This won't work if you are using cascade on the collection. You would likely get an exception: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance ... IUserCollectionType is the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

If your collection implements IList then you are able to map it as a usual bag collection.